# Configure EF Core CLI Parameters

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core project with a data access layer using EF Core 3.1.8 and also using version 3.1.8 of the cli tools. The presentation layer and the data access layer are in different projects. To run EF commands in the cli, I open a developer command prompt, navigate to the directory containing the data access layer and run a command such as

```
dotnet ef migrations add MyMigrationName --startup-project ../Site/Site.csproj
```

or

```
dotnet ef database update --startup-project ../Site/Site.csproj
```

`Site` is just a placeholder here. The actual project name is longer and it is inconvenient to provide the `--startup-project` argument each time I want to run a command. Is there somewhere I can configure that so that I can run commands more concisely like `dotnet ef database update`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a file named `ef.cmd` in the data access layer directory with the following contents:

```cmd
@dotnet ef --startup-project ..\Site %*
```

Then you can use:

```cmd
ef migrations add MyMigrationName
```

or

```cmd
ef database update
```

---

For completeness, another option is to use response files. This isn't as simple, but can be useful when you have multiple sets of options. (e.g. for multiple DbContexts)

Create a file named something like `identity.rsp` with the following contents.

```
--startup-project=..\Site
--context=IdentityContext
```

And use it like this.

```cmd
dotnet ef database update @identity.rsp
```

Comment: If you can think of a possibly better way, please comment on issue [#20862](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20862).

Comment: What is *.rsp file for? Is it Command Prompt feature? I can't use it.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @WillHuang I think it originated as [an MSBuild feature](https://learn.microsoft.com//visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-response-files). The logic of reading the file is built into dotnet-ef.